# How to add dynamic page inside class=“SwipedTabs-tabs” in ionic3?

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I have create a dynamically swiper tabs and i [image]have a 4 dynamic pages and i have to put this page inside this instead of the tabs and pages is >

i have add this page in this above tabs how to do this?

```html
public mainHomePage    : any = MainHomePage;
public connectionPage  : any = ConnectionPage ;
public chatPage        : any = ChatPage;
public sharePage       : any = SharePage;

<ion-segment  class="SwipedTabs-tabs"  >
  <ion-segment-button *ngFor='let tab of tabs ; let i = index ' value="IngoreMe" (click)="selectTab(i)"
  [ngClass]='{ "SwipedTabs-activeTab" : ( this.SwipedTabsSlider  &&this.SwipedTabsSlider.getActiveIndex() === i || (  tabs.length -1 === i&& this.SwipedTabsSlider.isEnd()))) }' >
    {{tab}}
  </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>

<ion-slides pager>

  <ion-slide>
    <h2>Page 1</h2>
  </ion-slide>

  <ion-slide>
    <h2>Page 2</h2>
  </ion-slide>

  <ion-slide>
    <h2>Page 3</h2>
  </ion-slide>

</ion-slides>
```

Comment: question is not clear, please explain your requirement

Comment: Sir i have created a swiper tab instead of the ion-tab but problem is that how to add above pages in the ion -slides check my updated fiddle how to add page inside ion-slide tag?

Answer (score 0):

May be this could be you are expecting.. please check this. 
use the corresponding selector inside the ion-slide. This will work fine if you want to load the html page to the tab.

```
<ion-segment  class="SwipedTabs-tabs"  (ionChange)="onSegmentChanged($event)" >
  <ion-segment-button *ngFor='let tab of tabs ; let i = index ' value="{{i}}">
    {{tab}}
  </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>

<ion-slides #mySlider>

  <ion-slide>
    <page-home></page-home>
  </ion-slide>

  <ion-slide>
    <page-connect></page-connect>
  </ion-slide>

  <ion-slide>
    <page-share></page-share>
  </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
    <page-chat></page-chat>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

ts

```
  onSegmentChanged(segmentButton) {
    console.log("Segment changed to", segmentButton.value);
    const selectedIndex = this.slides.findIndex((slide) => {
      return slide.id === segmentButton.value;
    });
    this.slider.slideTo(segmentButton.value);
  }
```

Comment: Sir i used this but i got error after add> . If 'page-mainHomePage' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

Comment: Sir, I will check this and read steps to remove this error and after remove "angular/material@2.0.0-beta.2"  from package.json but i am not using angular material in my app and i am not using angular4 i am using angular2 in ionic3?

Comment: no it is not possible for me to update to 4, is there is any another way to fix this?